# How can I obtain only word without All Punctuation Marks when I read text file?

Tags: matlab, text, textscan

The text file `abc.txt` is an arbitrary article that has been scraped from the web. For example, it is as follows:

> His name is "Donald" and he likes burger. On December 11, he married.

I want to extract only words in lower case and numbers except for all kinds of periods and quotes in the above article. In the case of the above example:

> {his, name, is, Donald, and, he, likes, burger, on, December, 11, he, married}

My code is as follows:

```
filename = 'abc.txt';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s','delimiter',{',','.',':',';','"','''});
fclose(fileID);
Cstr = C{:};
Cstr = Cstr(~cellfun('isempty',Cstr));
```

Is there any simple code to extract only alphabet words and numbers except all symbols?

Comment: You can use regular expressions

Comment: Do you want the results in a single string comma separated?

Comment: Finally, I want to make data of N by 1 cell type, each element of which is a word like 'banana'.

Comment: You say you want to extract only words in lower case but your desired output has `his` and `on`. Do you want to convert words at start of sentence (`His`, `On`) to lower case?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert all words to the ones in lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps are necessary as you want to convert certain words to lowercase.

[regexprep](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) converts words, which are either at the start of the string or follow a full stop and whitespace, to lower case.

In the `regexprep` function, we use the following pattern:

```
(?<=^|\. )([A-Z])
```

to indicate that:

- `(?<=^|\. )` We want to assert that before the word of interest either the start of string (`^`), or (`|`) a full stop (`.`) followed by whitespace are found. This type of construct is called a *lookbehind*.
- `([A-Z])` This part of the expression matches and captures (stores the match) a upper case letter (`A-Z`).

The `${lower($0)}` component in the regex is called a dynamic expression, and replaces the contents of the captured group (`([A-Z])`) to lower case. This syntax is specific to the MATLAB language.

You can check the behaviour of the above expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/h0DR8M/5).

---

Once the lower case conversions have occurred, [regexp](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) finds all occurrences of *one or more* digits, lower case and upper case letters.

The pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches lower case letters, upper case letters and digits.

You can check the behavior of this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/h0DR8M/4).

```
text = fileread('abc.txt')
data = {regexp(regexprep(text,'(?<=^|\. )([A-Z])','${lower($0)}'),'[a-zA-Z0-9]+','match')'}

>>data{1}

13×1 cell array

    {'his'     }
    {'name'    }
    {'is'      }
    {'Donald'  }
    {'and'     }
    {'he'      }
    {'likes'   }
    {'burger'  }
    {'on'      }
    {'December'}
    {'11'      }
    {'he'      }
    {'married' }
```

Comment: I do not understand the code because not knowing the regexprep now, but it works very nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @Danny_Kim I have added some information in my answer, including a couple of links to a regex demo. If you find the answer useful consider upvoting, thanks. If you find something unclear, let me know and I'll try and explain a bit more.